# Expo throws network error when both devices are connected to the same WiFi

Tags: react-native, expo, npx, metro-bundler, expo-go

When I run

> npx expo start

it will start a server and everything will come up properly. But when i scan the qr code in the terminal to run the app on my phone it says

> The internet connection appears to be offline. Make sure you're connected to the internet.

However, both my computer and my phone are on the same WiFi network

However, both my computer and my phone are on the same WiFi network

Comment: I might be an issue not even related to your internet connection. What does your app do? Are there any console errors or warnings?

Comment: @Alex no console errors, after scanning the QR and trying to run it it automatically says the internet appears to be offline even though it clearly is. When i try to reload the app it says "warn no apps connected". The app doesn't really have any serious function other than some buttons, email and password page and a couple other layouts.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/zndk26/expo_the_internet_connection_appears_to_be/ also, have tried disabling cellular data? (probably a stupid suggestion)